# How to call resource values on sailsjs

Tags: sails.js

I'm beginner on Sails.js. I'm trying to configure a controller. I found that code from [here](http://www.raweng.com/blog/2014/09/24/how-to-get-started-with-sails-js/).

```
   create: function (req, res) {
            var params = req.params.all()
            User.create({name:params.name, email:params.email}).exec(function createCB(err, created){
                return res.json({
                    notice: 'Created user with name '+created.name
                });
            });
      },
```

How to call values of this created resource? Something like that?

```
show: function (req, res) {
    return res.json({
      ??? - what should I write here?
    });
  },
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to show values from database that you saved in create method of your controller.

To do this, you need to query it:

```
show: function (req, res) {
    User.find().exec(function showUsers(err, users){
      if(err) return res.serverError();

      return res.json(users);
    });
}
```

This code snippet will query all created users and send that object to response.

Answer (score 1):

First : welcome to Sails.js!

hlozancic gave a good answer to query all stored data in that model.

Whenever an object is created in the database, it is given a unique ID (which is normally the primary index). If you want to retrieve *only* the object you created, you can pass the parameters into `.find()` or `.findOne()` or [one of the other methods available](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models).

```
show: function (req, res) {
  User.findOne(id).exec(function(err, users){
    if(err) return res.serverError();
    return res.json(users);
  });
}
```

For example, when you create your user, you defined `{name:params.name, email:params.email}` for that user. You could use these exact same params to find the user:

```
User.findOne({name:params.name, email:params.email})
    .exec(function(err, foundUser){ ... });
```